# IgnoreRoute with file extension is not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, ignoreroute

I have a Content folder and i want all the html files inside the Content folder from getting accessed, so i added this line at the top of the RegisterRoutes() method in the RouteConfig.cs file as follows

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{resource}.html");
```

but still i am able to access the file.

I even tried giving a static value like this

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{resource}.html");
```

and like this

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/demo.html");
```

but still was able to access the file, am i missing some thing, how can i acheive this behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps IIS is serving up the html pages without going through your application at all?

Comment: so how to get the desired result, according to the documentation IgnoreRoute wii ignore the specified file, then why is it not working, what am i doing wrong

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that perhaps your MVC application doesn't even come into the equation, check your IIS settings and see if it will serve up html pages itself.